# Where do i put the API Key in this simple get request?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am newbie when it comes to coding. I would simply like to know where to put the API KEY in this get request and display the $data as an array:

`$data=http::get('https://api.example.com/v1/conferences/active')->body();`

X-Api-Key: 5slkjn65656546556465

I tried `data=http::get('https://api.example.com/v1/conferences/active', 'X-Api-Key:5slkjn65656546556465')->body();`

`return response()->json(json_decode($data, true));`

Comment: What is the issue you're encountering ? how to use your API key depends on which api you're consuming. So i suggest that you read the documentation of the API you're trying to use. Also read this topic [ask] it will help you make your question more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: I keep geting error 401 when i try using the above method. I simply don't know where to place the api key and headers

Answer (score 0):

simply add it to requested url ex :

```
$data=http::get('https://api.example.com/v1/conferences/active?X-Api-Key=5slkjn65656546556465')->body();
```

i hope it was useful .

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. `$data=http::get('https://api.example.com/v1/conferences/active?X-Api-Key:us6e6c66f672d7cc8f7c26b69cd8614c7869c8c602
        dd($data);`